# Instance member cannot be used on Type struct

Tags: swift

I am using an MPMediaPickerController to select a song to play in the next ViewController. I need to save the MPMediaItemCollection to a variable in a struct. It calls a Instance member cannot be used on type error.

I have tried to change the type of the variable to a var instead of let. I also changed the type of the variable.

```
struct GlobalVariables {
    let song:MPMediaPickerController
}
func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
    GlobalVariables.song = mediaItemCollection //error here
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "tobrowse", sender: (Any).self)
}
```

I expected the variable to be set to the song class that the user chose, but instead it called the instance member cannot be used on type.

Comment: let song: MPMediaItemCollection

Comment: `GlobalVariables` is a struct. `song` is an instance variable of instances of `GlobalVariables`. But you're not trying to access the `song` property of a `GlobalVariables` instance, but rather, you're trying to access it as if it were a static property, which it isn't. In any case, global variables are shitty, much pain awaits down that road, and you should give more context to your problem so people can recommend a solution that doesn't involve globals

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
struct GlobalVariables {

static var song: MPMediaItemCollection

}

func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {

    GlobalVariables.song = mediaItemCollection 
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "tobrowse", sender: (Any).self)
}
```